# Can Nexus S communicate with Nokia 6131 by their NFC P2P function?

Tags: android, nokia, nfc

I am wondering if Nexus S can communicate with the elder NFC-enabled phone Nokia 6131i?

I know that the P2P protocol supported by Nokia 6131i is **NFCIP**, where the P2P function is done by the **NPP (NDEF Push Protocol)** on Nexus S (or, Android 2.3.3).

Did anyone ever test this? Can the two device communicate with each other by their own P2P support?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The two phones may establish a NFCIP1 connection, but they won't be able to communicate because the higher level protocols don't match.

Google is using it's own ndef push protocol which sits on top of NFCIP1 and LLCP. The nokia phone does not understand the ndef push protocol, so no data-exchange will be possible between the two phones.